# How can I test an Exception inside an async with?

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py

in my tests I did a coverage and I end up with untested parts inside an async with, what the coverage sees is the part about exceptions, my code is like this:

```py
 @classmethod
 async def update_eda_configuration(
            cls,
            configuration: ConfigurationInputOnUpdate
    ) -> Union['Configuration', ConfigurationOperationError]:

        async with get_session() as conn:
            result = await conn.execute(
                select(Configuration).where(Configuration.id==configuration.id))

            configuration_to_update = result.scalars().unique().first()
            if configuration_to_update is not None:
                configuration_to_update.attribute = configuration.attribute
                configuration_to_update.value = configuration.value
                try:
                    await conn.commit()
                    return configuration_to_update
                except Exception as e:
                    matches = re.findall(
                        pattern='DETAIL:.*',
                        string=str(e.orig),
                    )
```

Coverage looks like this:
[image]

I tried some tests but to no avail, trying for example patching to conn.commit.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you put everything inside the `async with` statement in its own function, then test that function on its own?

Comment: @RandomDavis I didn't understand, sorry

Comment: What does "test an exception" mean? You want to verify that the exception is raised? That the code within the except block executes properly? Something else?

Comment: @TeejayBruno I wish coverage would stop marking it as "yet to be tested", I wrote the tests to make it fail but coverage keeps highlighting it like this.